# The design layout of the verification modal window is broken

Tags: bug, design

The design layout for the verification modal window is broken in the latest Google Chrome (version 78) on Windows:

[image: Broken Layout]

EDIT: This appeared when I clicked "Post a question".

Comment: What browser (including version) and screen resolution are you using?  Providing that information could make this bug easier to replicate.  You can get that info from here: https://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/details/KmJmVm

Comment: Easier?? Did you find it hard to replicate?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to trigger that human verification, so I'm not sure that I can replicate it.   But when somebody does, it is good to have all the information so that this doesn't get closed as "can't reproduce the problem."

Comment: "I'm not actually sure how to trigger that human verification" You don't need to be sure. ", so I'm not sure that I can replicate it." I just clicked "Post a question". Added to report.

Comment: A web developer for SE is aware of this, as noted by a previous edit by @m0sa. We don't have any control over SE functions on our individual SE sites, so it might be best if you report system related bugs like this on the [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site where it will get more attention. Thanks.

Comment: If you're averse to reports like this which are in scope for this site ("Is your question about the Webmasters Stack Exchange community or website?") then I suggest you revise the statement of scope.

Comment: The community here is only able to answer questions to the best of their ability. We're unable to "revise" or change anything on the site except a single Help page. Design related issues are occasionally responded to here by Stack Exchange staff, particularly after redesigns. Other system or network related issues, such as verifications and spam filters, therefore might be better addressed over at the Meta site for Stack Exchange, where these issues are routinely discussed and get more immediate attention from the staff.

Comment: "The community here is only able to answer questions to the best of their ability. This isn't a question. It is feedback "We're unable to "revise" or change anything." I'm assuming someone who is able receives this feedback, but if there's a better channel for feedback to them, please do say.

Comment: The better place to report issues that effect all Stack Exchange sites, as opposed to just the Pro Webmasters site is https://meta.stackexchange.com/  as Dan already mentioned.   You appear to have posted there in the past, so presumably you already know how it works.    It seems weird to come here give "feedback" when you don't appear have used the Pro Webmasters site at all.