# Bogus "You can only post once every 40 minutes" when posting for the first time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This post attempt for the meta question [Verification layout broken](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/verification-layout-broken) was rejected with "You can only post once every 40 minutes" despite that I had not posted here before.

[image]

[image]